# jquery ajax php: page content not refrshing!

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i am trying to implement pagination. A set of 9 products are displayed at a time. then upon clicking on a "View More" button, the content of a div should refresh by AJAX and show the next set of 9 products..here's the php code

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['current'])){
        $query = "SELECT MAX(addedon) AS addedon FROM tags";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        report($result);
        $dated = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $recent = $dated['addedon'];
        $_SESSION['current'] = $recent;                 
}

$query = "SELECT id, addedon
                FROM tags
                WHERE addedon <= '{$_SESSION['current']}'
                ORDER BY addedon DESC
                LIMIT 9
                ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
report($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $_SESSION['current'] = $row['addedon'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $query = "SELECT name, image, cost
                    FROM tags, stock
                    WHERE tags.id={$id} AND stock.tagid = tags.id
                    ";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query);
    report($result1);
    $prodInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
    $pname = $prodInfo['name'];
    $pimg = $prodInfo['image'];     //the path to the actual image
    $pcost = $prodInfo['cost'];
    echo "<div class=\"oneproduct\">";
    echo "<h3>{$pname}</h3><br />";
    echo "<img src=\"{$pimg}\" height=\"{$ht}\" width=\"85px\" alt=\"prodImg\" /><br />";
    echo "<span>Rs. {$pcost}</span>";
    echo "<input type=\"image\" src=\"images/addcart.png\" class=\"addBtn\" />";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

after all the products would be fetched and displayed, the last product on the page is stored as 'current' variable of SESSION.
problem is: the ajax thing always returns the initial set of 9 products and as soon as i refresh the page, the next set of products are coming..how do i make my link change the content?

The ajax code:

```
$("#viewMore").bind('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'showNineProds.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'html',
                success:function(data){
                    $("div#nineproducts").html(data);
                },
                error:function(xhr, status){
                    alert("Problem");
                },
                complete:function(xhr, status){                     
                }
            });     
});
```

showNineProds.php simply calls a function that has been written above..

Comment: what does the report() call do?

Comment: it doesn't look like you are passing any parameters that would enable you to page your data. You are just selecting the same data every time. Take a look at this http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination get it working and when you get what's going on you should be able to figure out your problem :-)

Comment: @cromestant it's simply for error reporting..no big deal with that

Comment: @martswite i dont think i need to send any params to page here..dats where my session concept came in..i'm simply using a SESSION to take care of what records to fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is for the client-side code to specify with parameters to the AJAX call which "page" of records to be fetched.  By using a session variable like this, the server has no concept of which records to get at which time.  It's always going to return the "next" result.  So any time you load that web page, it's going to serve the "next" set of records.  There's no way to page backward in the result set.

Basically, you would store in local JavaScript values (or hidden form elements on the page, however you feel comfortable storing a value on the page) the information of the current result set and your AJAX call would send the necessary information to the server to return the requested result set.

For example, you could have a local JavaScript value that says which start record you're seeing and your page size:

```
startRecord = 1;
pageSize = 10;
```

Then if you click your "next" button the AJAX call would supply parameters to the server telling it what to fetch:

```
startRecord + pageSize, pageSize
```

You'd want to add a little bit of logic to determine if you're on the first or last page to disable "prev" and "next" functionality, of course.  And there's a lot more you can do (variable page sizes, filtering and searching, sorting, etc.) but this is the basic gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be sending back the info from the ajax call. basically yoi might be fetching the values on the DB but don't seem to be sending the data back to the call..
do you echo the result set in some format? I can't see that in the code. in any case you can't access the $session variables from the js... these are accessible server side in php.

Comment: yes but you can't access the $_SESSION variable from the JS code... you have to build a response ( xml, json or plain text) and then in the js on sucess method you need to parse that data, and build the new content for the DIV>

Comment: i totally understand that sir, i've edited my code to show u the full while loop. i'm using session variable to change the way my query processes.